# how to show a general consistent nonhomogeneous system (if that is even needed)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have this problem:

Show that the solution set of a consistent nonhomogeneous system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns does not form a subspace of R3.

I'm trying to wonder how to show the solution set in general, or if it even has to be in general (would showing an example suffice?)

i want to somehow write a 3x3 system and set it = (a,b,c) where a,b,c are not all = 0. So the abc part not all being 0 would display that it is non homogeneous. but im having trouble thinking of how to show a general solution set that is also consistent. i want to write 3 rows of x + y + z and each have different coeficients like k1 k2 k3 but I'm not sure if i should show it as k1 * the first row of x + y + z, k2 * the second, k3 * the third, or if thats wrong and it should be written a different way. also how would i show this is consistent in general ie: a,b,c is actually a solution? I'm pretty sure once i do this I can just apply the 3 rules to show its not a vector space under same ops as R3.

or does anyone know for sure if it would be correct to show an actual specific example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show that for any non-homogeneous system of linear equations one of the [vector space axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) does not hold in the solution space (i.e., it's not a subspace).  So, given an arbitrary such system, we need to find an axiom that is violated by the solution space.

*Sketch*: Since we have a *non-homogeneous* system of linear equations, at least one of the equations has the form $ax+by+cz=k$ where $k \neq 0$.  The solution space of the system of linear equations will therefore be contained in $$\{(x,y,z):ax+by+cz=k\}.$$  But, this set does not contain a particular vector that all vector spaces have.

Comment: oh! the zero vector :) thanks